# Partial/Full Trust mode verification in Asp .Net 4.0

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, medium-trust, partial-trust

I found the similar question on Msdn's forum but without answer (you can check it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxappcompatprerelease/thread/c7242563-8adb-4b7f-975e-9e741a7a693e/))
.Net 4.0 came with obsolete method

```
IsUnderHighTrust = SecurityManager.IsGranted( 
  new AspNetHostingPermission( AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted ) );
```

As a replacement it is suggested to use **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet**

```
var permission = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permission.AddPermission(
  new AspNetHostingPermission(AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted));

IsUnderHighTrust = permission.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet);
```

But **PermissionSet** is also requires Full trust mode.

So the obvious question - how to check under Asp .Net 4.0 if application is under Full or Medium Trust mode?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a try/catch around a block of code (like the PermissionSet check above) that requires full-trust and catch on a SecurityException?  It's not as pretty because this isn't what a try/catch should normally be used for, but seems it would accomplish the goal none the less.

Comment: That looks like a rude hack. I'd better use obsolete method. I'm wondered about such MS solution...